# Value of PHP variable as HTML link

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to pass the value of a PHP variable as HTML link:

HTML is :

```
There are <a href="displayrequests.php"> N </a> requests for help (click number to view requests).
```

**displayrequests.php** shows a table with **N** rows. Those rows are counted and stored on **$counter** variable.

I want $counter to be the HTML link to displayrequests.php (i.e N).

Note that $counter is not constant, but rather changes upon databases operations that are reflected in displayrequests.php (i.e. the number of rows may change).

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: see comments below

Answer (score 0):

Escape back to PHP execution mode to echo the variable in your HTML:

```
There are <a href="displayrequests.php"> <?php echo $counter; ?> </a> requests for help (click number to view requests).
```

Comment: Is this in regular HTML code in your script, or is it part of an `echo` statement?

Comment: I assumed this was in your PHP script.

Comment: No not in PHP. The HTML is from a .html file. I want to include the php variable in that html line of code that is in a .html file

Comment: This needs to be part of the PHP script that's reading from the database.

Comment: I wanted to display the php variable to the front-end (the .html file) which itself is the link back to the php file. Is that possible?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I suspect you need to use AJAX to query the back-end and fill in the HTML on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to echo the variable value...

```
There are <a href="displayrequests.php"> <? echo($n); ?> </a> requests for help (click number to view requests).
```

Comment: I guess you  mean  There are <a href="displayrequests.php"> <? echo($counter); ?> </a> requests for help (click number to view requests).